# Do theoretical particle physicists really believe the particles they work on do not exist?

Tags: particle-physics

Inspired by [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2022/sep/26/physics-particles-physicists) in *The Guardian*.

> In private, many physicists admit they do not believe the particles they are paid to search for exist – they do it because their colleagues are doing it

This makes no sense to me - there are surely better things to work on than stuff one believes to be wrong.

Is it really the case that many theoretical particle physicists don't believe the particles they work on exist?

Comment: Hossenfelder is worth reading, but so are [several physicists' replies](https://theguardian.com/science/2022/sep/30/particle-physics-a-brief-history-of-time-wasting).

Comment: Scientists try to simulate logic machines, not belief agents. They may hypothesize logical possibilities and particles unseen, and hope something would turn up, possibly, like the neutrino or the gluon, or the charmed quark, or the Higgs. Why should it be of interest what they "really believe", whatever that means?

Comment: Subatomic world has proven itself being counter-intuitive for humans. A century ago, physicists would not believe quantum mechanics was true. Some 50 years ago, they would not believe quarks were true. Science is not about belief, it is about establishing facts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably not aimed at the particles in the standard model. Probably also not the ones who study gravitons and quantized collective modes/quasi-particles like phonons, plasmons, polarons, etc. I'd bet even people who study dark matter are confident that it is real. This is probably more about the hypothetical particles that have been postulated for so long: axions, the supersymmetric pairs (the zoo of -inos), and strings. There is, as far as I'm aware, no direct evidence that those exist, just arguments that they should exist because they make the math prettier. A lot of people thought the LHC would find at least the lightest of the supersymmetry particles, and it came up empty on that account.

Much of it I would honestly characterize as being akin to looking for possible patterns of yet-to-be-observed epicycles in a Ptolemaic model of the solar system. I don't know what insight will lead to the sort of simplification that was achieved by Kepler, or even if that's possible, but we'll see.

As such, I think it's probably better to think of this as a Bayesian. The particle physicists hypothesizing these particles have a low confidence that their specific particle will pan out, I mean the track record for finding hypothetical particles has been mostly downhill since they failed to find proton decay generally predicted by grand unified theories (GUTs), but they're willing to place a bet in the hopes that it might. Before then there were some spectacular successes in predicting particles based on symmetry concerns (isospin, the [eightfold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)), etc), so it's not like they're unjustified in thinking that this sort of strategy could work again. It's just that the theory has gotten so far ahead of observed phenomena that it seems unlikely that these bets will pay off in our lifetimes, if ever.

To give another example, the Higgs was postulated based on mathematical concerns, and we found it. But saying "the" Higgs is a little misleading. The truth is that there was a job that needed to be done in the standard model, giving the weak gauge bosons mass without violating the gauge symmetry, so we could be confident that there was *something* that was doing that job, we just weren't sure exactly what. There were a whole family of possible Higgs particles that could do the job. So, the odds that any one arrangement of particles would turn out to be right was quite low, but the odds that one of them existed was quite high. Last I heard, the particle physicists were a bit disappointed because the evidence was pointing to the simplest Higgs model that doesn't point to new physics at even higher energy levels.

My own money is on the idea that we need to try something else. The "postulate symmetry, derive particles needed for the symmetry, and predict you'll find them at the next accelerator" is probably played out for a while.

Comment: The article names some of the particles - "preons, sfermions, dyons, magnetic monopoles, simps, wimps, wimpzillas, axions, flaxions, erebons, accelerons, cornucopions, giant magnons, maximons, macros, wisps, fips, branons, skyrmions, chameleons, cuscutons, planckons and sterile neutrinos, to mention just a few".

Comment: The problem with dark matter fields is a pretty obvious one: even if they don't exist it is not possible to rule them out without having spent a significant amount of effort on a series of null experiments. The same holds for supersymmetry etc.. These are, of course, rather conservative research areas, anyway, so it is hard to see why one would neglect them. Doing only the crazy, super-exotic stuff is not a viable research strategy.

Comment: "The Higgs" is a bit of a tough case of research funding. I talked to several theorists about LHC before it was even built and they all bet that it would find the Higgs and nothing else. They were almost correct. The problem is that there was no alternative to the LHC after SSC was cancelled. Everybody wanted the SSC but the US Congress wasn't willing to pay for it. That left HEP with no alternative. We had to build the LHC or the field would have more or less died at that time. This wasn't a science question, to begin with.

Comment: @FlatterMann At least with dark matter we have an observed phenomenon that needs explaining. With the Higgs we could be sure that there was something at that mass scale doing that job, even if we didn't know the details. With supersymmetry, I'm not aware of any phenomenon that needs it.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake Point taken. My main worry is that the ILC is the really misguided step. I am not sure we need a precision Higgs factory as an "intermediary step". I don't think we can get around a 100TeV machine like the FCC, though, or, if a new technology emerges that will allow 1000TeV class accelerators, a machine in that energy range. The main question there is not "if" but "how".

Answer (score 4):

> Is it really the case that many theoretical particle physicists don't believe the particles they work on exist?

I hope not.

To be an adequate researcher, in physics particularly, you have to focus on what you are researching, the way an artist focuses on his/her work.

I think this is a biased article by a person who does not understand that theorists in basic theories of physics explore many roads, hoping to find the one that models what nature is doing.

Some acquaintances may have expressed the belief that the complex particles predicted by the theory they are working on are tentative and may not be measurable, which is fair enough, and the statement is misinterpreted.

If a researcher is not behind his/her research, he/she should get out of
physics research, particularly theoretical physics.

Comment: But doesn't it seem like money would be better spent on alternative energy, like nuclear fusion or thorium reactors, than particle physics? It seems to me that the the goal of discovering a theory of everything has blinded physicists. I wonder if this is partly because most of them are men and think somewhat the same.

Comment: @jellyears Same argument could be made to spend money on Engineering rather than Physics. I find it very hard, if not impossible, to argue that a particular area of research isn't worth the money without using an argument that implies no science is worth the money when compared to something more tangible. Science is fundamentally based on long term projects and a lot of trial and error.

Comment: @jellyears The budget for theoretical physics is nothing compared to the one for nuclear fusion. Your argument is basically the same as the ones saying "but the LHC costs a lot, this money could be better used for something else". Truth is, you are no one to say what could money be better used for. This is much more complicated than that. Also, what does your last sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux "The budget for theoretical physics is nothing compared to the one for nuclear fusion." Do you have numbers for that? I'd find them interesting. I _think_ you're right, but frankly even fusion doesn't seem to get much spending either.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux My last sentence means that maybe we would be better off if more women were physicists. Our old dreams of going longer and going deeper into   space are worn out. We have a real problem. Climate change. We don't need such penis measuring contests now. Rockets. Particles go boom. Women have always been the real heroes throughout history because they're practical. Most of us are playing stupid games, trying to "win." Be the first. Go higher. We need actual heroes now and I don't see a man stepping up so maybe it will be a woman.

Comment: @J.G. For example, ITER has a budget of 21 billion USD, but there are other projects. Meanwhile, the LHC cost is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider#Cost) and is one of the most significant projects in physics ever built. I've also found [this](https://www.science.org/content/article/costs-balloon-u-s-particle-physics-megaproject), a "mega project" of 3 billion USD... I agree with you that fusion doesn't get much spending, but once again, things are way more complicated than what jelly ears said.

Comment: @jellyears  you say " We have a real problem. Climate change." If any discipline claiming to be doing science "climate cange" is dominated by men who have an agenda to pursue, mostly about money , but not only, I spent a few years after my retirement on what used to be "anthropogenic global warming" and has morphed to "climate change" by men of course, and am convinced that the data over millennia show that the climate is changing, BUT humans have little effect on it, like mosquitoes on the body. At 82 I am amused by all this climate change, and order the sun to stop  fantasies .

Comment: @annav  humans have accelerated global warming, it's a fact.

Comment: @jellyears  Only locally . like mosquito bites, the influence of humans is verifiable.  Sleep on.

Answer (score 1):

She is referring to particles in speculative theories like Garrett Lisi's E8, various string theories, GUT, and SUSY, etc. The experimental physicists and engineers sometimes have theories but mostly they are testing others weird ideas. Sabine makes good arguments that it's probably a waste of money and resources. It's unfortunate, but there's no particular reason to assume that the grand unified theory is something we can confirm or even could confirm. So, experimental physicists are like drunks looking for their keys around the lamp post because that is where the light is shining brightest.

Comment: Most of experimental particle physicists do not test "weird ideas". Most research goes into precision measurements of the Standard Model phenomena and properties. In any particle physics conference, "weird ideas" are represented in the "exotica" stream which is by far not the most active one.